# Generating list of position (1, (2, 3), 4, (5, 6)) how?

Tags: python

Hello  i was wonder how to create list of integer / tuples for a list of positions for string slicing.
same example as in title just make a list of this format:
(1, (2, 3), 4, (5, 6))

```
# my current attempt: 
str_input, decrypted_str = "tester", ""
num_lists = [[x] + [(x + 1, x + 2)] for x in range(0, len(str_input), 4)]
for clist in num_lists:
    for position in clist:
        if isinstance(position, int):
            decrypted_str += str_input[position]
        else:
            decrypted_str += str_input[position[0]:position[1]+1]
print(decrypted_str)
```

this results in "teser", but output should be tester.

Comment: you shouldn't edit the question and invalidate an answer. You could comment under the answer that it did not solve your problem. Or at least add another section in the question showing your second try. But your edit makes some answers irrevelant and it's not nice. People put time and effort to answer so it's not respectful to invalidate their work

Answer (score 1):

The line before the last one should be

```py
decrypted_str += str_input[position[0]:position[1]+1]
```

because 1:5 means 1,2,3,4 but not 5

Comment: That is because s·he has edited his question after I answered.

Besides, the second line should be
```
num_lists = [[x] + [(x + 1, x + 2)] for x in range(0, len(str_input), 3)]
```
as it was in the original question

Comment: Oh... @PythonNoob you shouldn't edit the question and invalidate an answer. You could comment here that this did not solve your problem. Or at least add another section in the question showing your second try. But your edit makes this answer irrevelant and it's not nice. People put time and effort to answer so it's not respectful to invalidate their work